# Can we skip optional parameters in builder pattern in java?

Tags: java, builder

I am new to object patterns and stuck at this problem. How we handle optional parameters in builder pattern? Can we set such parameters later using Setter methods, after building an object using builder pattern? Or do we need to set them at builder only?

Comment: Typically fields in a builder object are non-final, so just set the value of the default when you declare the field, and then make your chained setter method like normal

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create methods in your builder class for setting optional parameters. That is what builder design pattern is meant for. It is majorly used with Factory and Abstract Factory design pattern when object is too heavy with lot of attributes and its creation is complex.

You can follow this link for more detail:
http://www.journaldev.com/1425/builder-design-pattern-in-java